# Dismiss custom popover dialog

Tags: swift

I need to dismiss modal dialog(s) when tapping outside of it's area. This works automatically when the view is defined in a storyboard and presented like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Services", bundle: nil)
let pinCodeController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PinCodeController")

pinCodeController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
pinCodeController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)

let presentationController = pinCodeController.popoverPresentationController
presentationController?.sourceView = pinCodeButton

self.present(pinCodeController, animated: true)
```

However, as I am not using storyboards I have almost the same code for presenting my view. This code presents the view but it will not dismiss when tapping outside of its boundary.

```
popoverFromSourceController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popoverFromSourceController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 300)

let presentationController = popoverFromSourceController.popoverPresentationController
presentationController?.sourceView = self.popoverFromSourceViewButton

present(popoverFromSourceController, animated: true)
```

Can anyone see what the difference is and why the behaviour is different? Do I need to somehow add a click event to the underlying view in order to dismiss the popup?

I have the same issue, though somewhat different when presenting this same popup from a UIBarButtonItem. My navigationcontroller has two barbuttons and when the dialog is presented via the first button, it will then automatically dismiss when the second button is clicked. But, clicking in the main view does not dismiss the dialog.

Full source code: https://github.com/igunther/CleanController

Anyone?

**Update**

Added this code, but still not working:

```
popoverFromSourceController.isModalInPopover = false
```

Comment: Can't reproduce any issue. I ran your project. I tapped the button that says "popover from sourceView". The popover appeared. I tapped outside it. The popover vanished. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe you are just confused about your own project? The _other_ button, the one that _says_ "Show popover", okay, the view that _that_ one presents does not dismiss when you tap outside it. But it, despite the name, is not a popover. It's just an ordinary presented view controller using `overCurrentContext`. So popover behavior would not be expected for that one.

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to run the project! This is very strange, when I tap the red view behind the brown popover, the dialog stays put. The other button is not relevant to this problem and you are right it is not a popover. Sorry for the bad naming and confusion about that button. However, it does not make sense that the popover dismisses automatically in your simulator and not mine.

Comment: The "red view behind the brown popover" is correct. I tap on that and the brown popover vanishes. — Okay, let's play version games. I'm running this under Xcode 10.2 on Mojave. The simulator is the iPad Air 2 simulator. How about you?

Comment: I was also going to suggest the version game, I have the latest but no need. I figured it out. When I ran the code from "obabovic" below, I was not getting any tapped event. This, combined with the fact that it has been working on your end all along got me thinking about the simulator. So I closed my simulator and restarted it, then my initial code worked and also the gesture recognizer. No wonder this was confusing. So somehow my simulator was playing games with me. But your answers helped me out of the situation as I was sure something was wrong with the code. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: I would suggest that either you give that as a formal answer (perfectly legal and encouraged on Stack Overflow) or else perhaps delete the question. The problem is solved and we don't want to leave the question hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers: The code presented is viable as matt commented on in the first place. Problem was that the simulator was not functioning and needed a reboot. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering - have you tried implementing the behavior with a UITapGestureRecognizer?

For example:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
  let dismissTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissPopover(_:)))

  view.addGestureRecognizer(dismissTapGesture)
}


// This is invoked if the user taps anywhere outside the modal bounds. 

@objc func dismissPopover(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
      let point = sender.location(in: view)

      if !self.view.frame.contains(point) {
          // We have tapped outside the popover
      }
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should be working correctly. Alternatively, instead of adding the gesture recognizer on the popover view, try adding it in the VC that presents the popover.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, compiled your code but did not get any gesture. Got me thinking that something fishy was going on with the simulator. After reboot all ok. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Cheers! Good luck!